# OS X distribution.dist automated validation/evaluation

Tags: macos, validation, installation, distribution, requirements

I am doing some research to see whether I can automatically/programatically validate a distribution.dist file that came from a valid os x pkg/dmg.

Here is the situation:
I have some valid os x applications in dmg and pkg format. I have extracted their distribution.dist files and would like to determine which machines (let's assume there are many) these packages would install successfully on. I don't want to copy the entire pkg/dmg files to every machine and then run the "installer" command to see if the installation would succeed or fail. This would consume excessive bandwidth/resources. Instead, I would like to do something more lightweight like use a script/command/binary that could evaluate only the distribution.dist requirements on the machine and then return if they are met or not.

I figure the hardest part of solving this problem would be how the "Installer Javascript" scripts would be executed/evaluated. Since I do not see that Apple has given external access to those particular libraries.

One idea I have is to use pkgbuild and create pkg files with no payload. Then I could use the "/usr/sbin/installer" command to "install" these "empty" pkgs. The install checks would be performed and the file size would be small. However, I am hoping there is a more elegant way of solving this problem.

Thanks.